# OSM Editing routing algorithm

Tags: routes, openstreetmap

I'm using Javascript with Open Street Map in a webapp. Is it possible to:

- Access traffic light locations?
- Edit a routing algorithm to avoid traffic lights?
- Display in the webapp the route without traffic lights?

Comment: This sounds like server functionality rather than something to do in the browser.

Comment: Duplicate: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/30121/tweaking-routing-algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in general this is possible but as @flup points out, nobody would realizes global routing in pure Javascript at client side (amount of data, complexity, performance, ...) .

Instead you use or setup an [existing routing solution](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) that publishes an RPC/... webinterface and can be embedded using JS. As all of the existing solutions are Open Source, you can adapt than to give edges with traffic lights a worse weight than without. Currently no solution [seems to take them](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) into account, I guess for several reasons:

- not well mapped everywhere
- different level of details to map crossings with trafficlights (just one vs. one per direction)

So I guess the preprocessing isn't that easy esp. if you are unfamilar with OSM data (model and current use of tagging schemas and coverage). I guess a good starting point for analyses would be the [TrafficMining](http://code.google.com/p/trafficmining/) framework that is build to test routing algorithms.

Comment: Good ideas.
In regards to Traffic Mining framework, are there any alternatives? 

Because w/e I try to load a .osm file I get the below error: 

Jan 22, 2014 10:10:04 PM de.lmu.ifi.dbs.trafficmining.LoadGraphListener propertyChange
SEVERE: null
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2153445071"

The .osm file: 
http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/monaco.html

Comment: Please don't make crossposts anymore, as this is very time consuming for a voluntiering support community https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/30121/tweaking-routing-algorithm

Comment: traffic lights are relative easy to implement and parse but routing engines have a lot more to do, so that often this is neglected. But feel free to +1 [this feature request](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/75) ;)